# How to get RPi to generate a triangle wave, then outputting a PWM signal

Tags: raspbian, gpio, python, rpi.gpio, pwm

I want my Raspberry Pi B+ Model to generate a triangle wave and output a PWM signal from one of the GPIO pins, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this. All I want it to do is add some small length to every next pulse until it hits 100%, then it subtracts some amount from every pulse width. So if the triangle wave is at its high peak the PWM is at 100% duty cycle, and if it's at its low peak the PWM is at 0% duty cycle. Any ideas or suggestions? Thank you in advance!

New note: For 6.28 seconds from 0% to 100% at 500 Hz

Comment: You need to clarify your requirements.  As a minimum the length of the maximum pulse, the number of steps between 0 and maximum pulse, the time spent at each step.

Comment: 6.28 seconds from 0% to 100% at 500 Hz

Answer (score 1):

There may be many ways of doing what you want.  You still need to tighten up your requirements.  There are many variables which are not clear.

Here is a possible solution using my [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) library.

[webm video](http://abyz.me.uk/videos/sweep-pwm.webm)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# 2014-10-22
# sweep-pwm.py
# Public Domain

import time

import pigpio

FREQUENCY=500
SWEEP=6.28
GPIO=4
LOOPS=10

pi = pigpio.pi() # Connect to local Pi.

f = pi.set_PWM_frequency(GPIO, FREQUENCY)

if f != FREQUENCY:
   print("Can't set frequency {}.".format(FREQUENCY))
   pi.stop()
   exit()

# Find real number of steps from min to max
# and use this value in the loop.

r = pi.get_PWM_real_range(GPIO)

pi.set_PWM_range(GPIO, r)

for i in range(LOOPS):

   for s in range(r+1):
      pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(GPIO, s)
      time.sleep(SWEEP/r)

pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(GPIO, s) # Stop PWM on gpio.
pi.stop() # Close connection.
```